# how to let vertical-align middle work with display inline-block

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

html

```
<ul class="tabs-bottom">
<li><a href="#tab-1">Booking</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">Special Offers</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.tabs-bottom{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tabs-bottom li{
    width: 216px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VxnS5/)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to vertically align? The text inside the tab?

Comment: yes, The text inside the tab.

Comment: Cannot work. Need to use `display:table-cell;` http://jsfiddle.net/VxnS5/1/

Comment: Yeah, I can do that with display: table-cell but I'm searching for with inline-block

Comment: You won't get it to do it with just inline-block. You'll need to use table-cell to get each individual item to vertically center. You can use inline-block to vertically center the blocks themselves, but the text itself needs to be centered using table-cell.

Answer (score 2):

I can do this with display table-cell but I strongly searching for with display inline-block

here is working demo with display table-cell [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VxnS5/2/)

```
.tabs-bottom{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.tabs-bottom li{
    width: 216px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with other display property, you can use `diaplsy:table-cell` like this

```
.tabs-bottom li{
    width: 216px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete css you need to have it working. 
This also handles very long texts, which wrap around (multi-line link texts):

```
.tabs-bottom{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tabs-bottom li{
    width: 216px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabs-bottom li a
{
    line-height:16px; /*This is in place, to prevent inheriting the li's line-height*/
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can test it in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vVnR5/

---

**Notice**

jsFiddle doesn't seem to work in IE 7 and 8, so i couldn't test it.

Comment: You also have set line-height.

Comment: @C-Link: Yes, indeed, that is needed.

Answer (score -1):

If they're only ever going to be one line, you can center them with line-height,

```
.tabs-bottom li{
    width: 216px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height:55px
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It's trickier if you want a multi-line center, but it can be achieved using `display:table-cell;`

**EDIT** Here is a version where it will center regardless of number of lines http://codepen.io/robsterlini/pen/btqjv but remember that it will default back to appearing at the top for IE7 and below ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)).

Comment: height may be unknown, so I need to display with vertical-align middle